# iOS drawing with CGContextStrokePath() lagging/crashing when drawing while zoomed in

Tags: ios, ios4, uiscrollview, quartz-2d, cgcontext

### Rundown of Problem

I an iPad app with a UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView. I want the user to be able to draw on-top of the UIImageView by using a stylus and/or their finger.

I have it working well on the simulator, but it completely lags out (and sometimes crashes) on the iPad. The problem becomes far more evident when you try and dry **while already zoomed-in** on the UIScrollView; it becomes incredibly laggy (essentially freezes) and then crashes.

(Scrolling on the UIScrollView does not conflict with drawing, as it is set to require 2 fingers when drawing is active.)

### The Code

Here are the relevant methods. These methods are all inside of the view which handles the drawing:

```
 /**
 When the user first starts writing
 */
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    isMouseMoved = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 

    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:imageView];

    if(isEraserOn){
        [self changeEraserLocationTo:currentPoint];
    } 

    [self resetEraser:FALSE];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:imageView];
} 

/**
 When the user first starts moving the pen
 */
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    isMouseMoved = YES; 
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:imageView]; 

    // Setting up the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
    [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

    if (isEraserOn) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), eraserRadius);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
        CGRect eraserFrame = eraser.frame; 
        eraserFrame.origin.x = currentPoint.x - (eraserRadius/2);
        eraserFrame.origin.y = currentPoint.y - (eraserRadius/2);
        eraser.frame = eraserFrame;
    } else {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), penRadius);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, 1.0); 
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeNormal);
    }

    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    lastPoint = currentPoint; 
    mouseMoved++; 

    if (mouseMoved == 1) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    } 
} 

/**
 When the user stops writing
 */
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    [self resetEraser:TRUE]; 

    if (!isMouseMoved) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
        CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

        [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

        CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, penRadius);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, r, g, b, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);
        imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Any help with this issue would be **greatly** appreciated; I'm really at my wits end with this one...

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently developed an app that allows for drawing on images.  The way I implemented it was to create another UIView layer and then do my graphics/gl drawing on that view.  Then you can move all your touch events to the gl view.  I haven't had any performance issues with my current implementation and it shouldn't be changed when zoomed in.  Also check your memory, you may be leaking.

Take a look at the following apple code:

[GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

as you have said that you are using stylus or finger, So while using stylus/finger, how are you handling touch events, I mean to say that, when a user holding a stylus in his hand, will rest his hand on ipad screen and then try to write,(as we write on a paper) so whether your stylus work in this scenario.